# Motivation en français et en anglais

Tags: traduction, anglais, faux-amis

Y a-t-il des cas où le mot motivation de l'anglais est un faux ami du mot motivation du français ?
Considérons un exemple. Pour le titre d'un élément de l'aperçu du cours en algèbre linéaire, j'écrirais en anglais

> Motivation to study  linear algebra. (I.e. why study  linear algebra; what is the point)

La phrase 'Motivation to study  linear algebra' est-elle rendue en français par

> Motivation pour étudier l'algèbre linéaire.

On m'a dit d'éviter la tournure française car 'motivation' en français est utilisé pour parler de quelqu'un qui est motivé ; de la lettre de motivation, etc. Est-ce vrai ?

Comment: "car 'motivation' en français est utilisé pour parler de quelqu'un qui est motivé", en anglais aussi.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256682/why-study-linear-algebra Motivation is used twice there. It's motivation in French too because in **English** motivation means what leads you to do something.

Comment: @Lambie I do not understand what is the problem. Motivation in English and French can have similar meanings. But 'Motivation to study linear algebra.'  (I.e. why study linear algebra; what is the point) as a title of slide in a course outline is not conveyed in French by '(La) Motivation pour étudier l'algèbre linéaire'. Colleagues and students alike (French native speakers) suggested that I do not use motivation in this context. I wanted to check this assertion as I do always. I trust the answers of users like jlliagre (among others).

Comment: @Lambie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYepD1GyyL0 ; https://www.coursera.org/lecture/linear-algebra-machine-learning/motivations-for-linear-algebra-N4W2c ; http://www.disconzi.net/Teaching/MAT196-Spring-15/extras/Motivation_VS.pdf

Comment: @Lambie https://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic1/1a/1a_1intro.html ; https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/jl30kcwntnn7f1/jl45clghyj1fq.

Comment: **L’espoir d’améliorer sa situation serait maintenu et la motivation pour faire des études également**. https://www.parenteau.fr/?page_id=293

Comment: Dimitri: Motivation basically has one meaning in English. Do you mean the definition used by educators and psychologists? Or do you mean: **the reasons for studying it**? This is not at all clear. The French speakers here seem to think you mean something other than the word motivation in English. Do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'après le sens que tu indiques (*why study linear algebra; what is the point*), ***intérêt*** est plus indiqué :

> **Intérêt de l'étude de l'algèbre linéaire.**

Ceux qui t'on conseillé d'éviter ***Motivation** pour étudier [...]* ont eu bien raison.

La **motivation**, c'est une impulsion intérieure qui pousse quelqu'un à faire quelque chose alors que dans ta question, tu décris plutôt les **motifs**, les **raisons** qui vont permettre à cette motivation de naître ou pas.

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, mais la question était pour motivation.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, et ma réponse indique que motivation ne convient pas.

Answer (score 2):

Considering it's not [impossible](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=60929005#60929005) to replace *motivation* with [*rationale*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/rationale) in this title introducing content discussing why we study linear algebra and what's the point of all this, I would think *raison* is adequate in context. Without the article and followed with *de*:

> *Raison de l'étude de l'algèbre linéaire.*

I don't believe using *motivation* with this exact turn of phrase is impossible in this context but I wouldn't advise it, as I believe it mostly triggers references to ideas which are completely outside of the scope of the *rationale*, as evidenced elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Le conseil semble judicieux. Si on se reporte  à la définition du dictionnaire ([TLFi, motivation](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/motivation)), on s'aperçoit que seulement « **I** » pourrait convenir, mais « motivation » est le substantif qui correspond à « [motiver, **I A**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/motiver) » ; comme ce verbe et son sens ne sont utilisés que si le sujet est une personne (Qqn motive qqc), ni le verbe ni le nom correspondant ne peuvent être utilisés. Voilà donc quelle serait la raison pour ne pas pouvoir utiliser ce mot.

Cependant, le verbe « [**B** Qqc.motive qqc.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/motiver) », s'il n'y correspond pas un substantif de même racine et sens, est un verbe qui lui-même,  vu sa définition, peut être utilisé.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/motiver)) B. − Qqc.motive qqc. **Faire naître le motif, les raisons de quelque chose; susciter**.
> ♦ Elle avait représenté pour Swann, au moment où il l'avait vue, une personne définie, avec qui il avait des souvenirs communs qui avaient motivé chez lui le mouvement de s'approcher d'elle, le geste de la saluer (Proust, Swann, 1913, p.415).

La phrase suivante est de ce fait une traduction correcte.

- *Motivation to study linear algebra.*
- Ce qui motive l'étude de l'algègre linéaire

Comment: The French needs La motivation in this case; La motivation pour étudier machin-chouette. En anglais, on n'utilise pas l'article pour une idée général pour les mots abstraits.

Comment: @Lambie First, if you read my answer, you would see that it is not proper to use "motivation", and that I do not use it. Second, iif you refer to the text of the query, I have to say that in titles the use of the aticle is not necessary. See this, for instance : [Simplification et modernisation du droit de la famille](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Simplification_et_modernisation_du_droit/zrlODwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22simplification+de+la%22&pg=PA133&printsec=frontcover), La simplification de la procédure pénale, ….

Comment: **I disagree completely with you**. Read my answer. From a French website, the word motivation + études.  Read the Larousse definitions. In titles, but who says this is a title?? Ce qui motive is what motivates.

Comment: Votre goût pour la création, votre curiosité vis-à-vis de l’époque et **votre motivation pour faire des études dans une école supérieure d’art sont vos atouts**. https://www.esaaa.fr/esaaa/agenda/concours-2020-1re-annee-automne/

Comment: @Lambie You are confusing two things: "motivation" in French, as what drives you towards studies, a psychological drive, and "motivation" in English, as plain reasons (utilitarian reasons) for doing something, which in French is not named "motivation" and which have nothing to do with the psychology of the individual; this second concept is the proper one in the  scientific context of the study of linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Quoique pas faux compte tenu des différents sens de **motivation** en français et en anglais, ça ne me semble pas idiomatique dans le contexte proposé. Je suggérerais plutôt **justification**.

> **Justification** de l'étude de l'algèbre linéaire.

Cela revient aussi à exposer les motifs mais ça élimine la connotation subjective qu'on pourrait entendre avec **motivation**.

Answer (score -1):

LAROUSSE

[motivation en français](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/motivation/52784)

MOTIVATION

1. Ce qui motive, explique, justifie une action quelconque ; cause : La motivation du refus doit être explicite. [*la même chose en anglais*; What motivates, explains or justifies some action or cause; **BUT** *also reason in English*: The reason for the refusal must be explicit.]
2. Raisons, intérêts, éléments qui poussent quelqu'un dans son action ; fait pour quelqu'un d'être motivé à agir : Ils n'ont pas de motivations suffisantes pour vous écouter. [*la même chose en anglais*; reasons, interests or elements that impel someone to act, etc.]
3. Formulation par écrit de motifs d'un acte administratif. [legal term, **not the same in English**//*statement of reasons*]
4. Ensemble des facteurs qui déterminent le comportement d'un agent économique. (Les études de motivation du consommateur sont utilisées lors des études de marché et de l'établissement des campagnes de publicité.) [*la même chose en anglais*; All the factors determining the behavior of an economic agent]
5. Relation de nécessité plus ou moins étroite établie par le locuteur entre un signe linguistique (signifiant) et la réalité qu'il désigne (signifié). [*same thing*: *degree of motivation* and arbitrariness of a signified and a sign; Necessary relationship that is closer or farther away that a speaker establishes between a linguistic sign (signifier) and the reality it designates (signified)]
   **6. Grande catégorie de déterminants internes des comportements, des activités psychologiques et des états subjectifs. [*la même chose en anglais*; motivation, in psychology]**

***Les traits sémantiques (grosso  modo) des termes sont presque les mêmes***. **Mais, en anglais, on n'utilise par le terme venant des resources humaines: lettre de motivation**. We say: **letter of intent and/or interest** or letter explaining why you want a job.

- En ce qui concerne les études:

> **Motivation : une clé pour réussir ses études**
>
> Tags : lycée, motivation, psychologie, réussite, étudiant
>
> Pour l'étudiant, le manque de motivation est un vrai handicap qui
> suffit à expliquer bien des échecs. Au contraire la motivation est une
> énergie puissante qui peut mener de réussite en réussite. Mais comment
> la trouver et la garder ?

[motivation: domaines_les études](https://www.reussirmavie.net/Motivation-une-cle-pour-reussir-ses-etudes_a995.html)

- Là, le terme en français et en anglais venant de la psychologie serait le même.

**La** motivation pour étudier l'algèbre linéairePar contre, en anglais, l'article n'est pas necéssaire pour les mots abstraits.

La motivation et les maths:
[méthode maths](https://www.methodemaths.fr/motivation/)

**LA MOTIVATION**

> Introduction
> Pourquoi faire un chapitre **sur la motivation** ? Comme
> dit dans la section précédente, **c’est la motivation qui va te
> permettre d’adopter la bonne attitude pour travailler en suivant les
> conseils donnés depuis le début.** En effet, tu as remarqué que suivre
> tous les conseils demande un minimum de temps et d’investissement. Or
> travailler les maths ou la philosophie n’est pas forcément ce que tu
> fais pour te détendre…
>
> Ainsi, il faut trouver **la motivation nécessaire qui va te pousser
> naturellement à travailler**.

La motivation en mathématiques

> TABLE DES MATIERES
> 2 **Qu’est-ce que la motivation** ?
> 2.1 La motivation en lien avec les performances à l’école primaire
> 2.2 Les différentes pédagogies
> 3 Les facteurs de la motivation
> 3.1 La Pyramide des besoins selon Maslow et les facteurs de motivation selon Herzberg
> 3.2 La motivation extrinsèque et intrinsèque
> 3.3 Le point de vue de grands psychologues du XXème siècle
> 3.4 Les travaux de Ryan et Déci et l’autodétermination (1985)

[Mémoire présenté en vue de l’obtention du grade de master](https://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/dumas-01834520/document)
soutenu par
MARTINET Alexandra et MOREL Ophélie

**La** motivation pour étudier l'algèbre linéaire

"**La** motivation pour étudier l'algèbre linéaire"